# Rewrite URL in web.config but disregard query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule in web.config

```
<rewrite url="~/product/(.+)" to="~/outbound-link-proxy.aspx?product=$1" />
```

This should rewrite (e.g.)

```
mydomain.com/product/car
```

to

```
mydomain.com/outbound-link-proxy.aspx?product=car
```

This is working fine. However I have noticed that some sites are linking to mine and adding their own query string on the end. I don't mind this but it is breaking my rewrite.

```
mydomain.com/product/car?foreignQueryString=983249
```

How can I create a rewrite rule to preserve my original rewrite but disregard any query strings so that

```
mydomain.com/product/car?foreignQueryString=983249
```

still rewrites to

```
mydomain.com/outbound-link-proxy.aspx?product=car
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer

```
<rewrite url="~/product/(.+)\?(.+)" to="~/outbound-link-proxy.aspx?product=$1" />
```

A \? to match a literal question mark then (.+) to match number of any other characters to end of string.